# PHP long ternary operator line and 120 char line long PSR rule

Tags: php, conditional-operator, psr-2

Is there a good way to format long ternary operator line ? Let's say :

```
$order = new Order($this->isProfessionalChildCollaborator($this->getUser()) ? $this->getUser()->getParent() : $this->getUser());
```

This is too long according to 120 char per line defined in PSR. Should I do :

```
$order = new Order(
    $this->isProfessionalChildCollaborator($this->getUser()) ?
    $this->getUser()->getParent() :
    $this->getUser()
);
```

Or is there any other best practice?

Comment: Cache `$this->getUser()` call to reduce the chars. You can also wrap `isProfessionalChildCollaborator` inside some smaller method name.

Comment: Is using an `if` clause instead of ternary an option?

Comment: According to me, your proposals @vivek_23 and @kerbholz are more workarounds. Imagine the expression as not reduceable, and the question still remains. `if` usage might be the last stage, but my question is around formatting guidelines on ternary.

Comment: @nbonniot Well, I usually don't initialize constructors with ternary if conditions. So I never ran across these nitpicks.  I pass them and decide them in the constructor itself or make use of subtype polymorphism

Answer (score 3):

No rules in PSR for that, but I am prefer
[this style, described in](https://thenerdery.github.io/php-standards/standards/general.html#ternary-operator)

```
$documentProcessingIndicatorId = $object->isProcessingDocument()
    ? $object->getDocumentProcessingIndicatorId()
    : null;
```